# polymerization of 1,3,5-trichlorobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I am interested in carrying out the polymerization of 1,3,5-trichlorobenzene, wondering if anyone had ever successfully performed this polymerization? I would think it might be possible to carry out this polymerization by applying the method of "nickel-catalyzed coupling of aromatic dihalides", which was used in the literature:

Wang, Y.; Quirk, R. P. Synthesis and Characterization of Poly(benzoyl-1,4-phenylene)s. 2. Catalyst Coligand Effects on Polymer Properties. *Macromolecules* **1995,** *28* (10), 3495–3501. DOI: [10.1021/ma00114a001](https://doi.org/10.1021/ma00114a001).

[image: 1,3,5-trichlorobenzene]
[image: trichlorobenzene polymer]

Comment: [Here](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja9093956) is a good example to begin with. You may need iodide and/or bromide instead of chlorides.

Comment: Also, would you put the correct reference of  "nickel-catalyzed coupling of aromatic dihalides"? I cant find it in 1995 issue 10 of Macromolecules as you mentioned it.

Comment: Now what is your question? idgi

Comment: @Karl I guess he wants to make this graphene-like structure in the picture. I sure won't work though.

Comment: Won't work because reasons I already told here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/what-would-you-call-the-polymerised-sheet-like-polymer-arising-from-fittig-react

Comment: @Mithoron  is it possible to use monomers such as 1,3,5-tris(chloromethyl)benzene,  1,3,5-Tribromobenzene, 1,3,5-Tris(bromomethyl)benzene, 1,3,5-Triiodobenzene, etc., to carry out the polymerization to make graphene-like sheet structures?

Comment: My point is there's no way to make such spontaneous organisation of matter that is *not* thermodynamically preferred. In your mind you imagine that molecules will bind as you like - in this case they won't.

Comment: So, unless you got some really weird enzyme made, you'll just get a mixture of every possible oligomer, i.e. some gunk.

Comment: Precisely what will happen: "gunk". ;) At low turnover, oligomers, then a rubbery substance, which finally cures into a solid, unstructured brick.

Comment: I had [deja vu](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/what-would-you-call-the-polymerised-sheet-like-polymer-arising-from-fittig-react#comment339876_75948)… so I am obliged to repeat myself: The first coupling will already be so far out of planarity, it is a biphenyl after all, that there would never be a 2D-structure. I believe with the third molecule the whole thing will start to coil. My best guess would be that there might be string-like oligomers.

Comment: On the technicality though. I don't think that a question that results in the answer (or along those lines) "this is impossible", warrants closure. Sure it is an unsatisfactory outcome, but I don't see the aspect of being actually off-topic.